# Submitting a form in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to submit a form with the standard form that was given in the SDK i downloaded.

Anyone have any information on how it's passed? Any tips as to how to pass it?

I'm trying to make a very simple submit form to collect some information.

```
{                    title: 'Register',
                    iconCls: 'add',
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    url: 'contact.php',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    scrollable: true,



                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'Opt In',
                            instructions: 'Want more info on Monster Energy? Opt-in to receive updates. ',

                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    label: 'First Name',
                                    name: 'fname',
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    label: 'Last Name',
                                    name: 'lname',
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                                    label: 'Email',
                                    name: 'email',
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                                    label: 'Phone',
                                    name: 'phone',
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Send',
                            ui: 'confirm',
                            handler: function() {
                                this.up('formpanel').submit();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

contact.php

```
<?phpinclude_once "config.php";
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Cannot select db" . mysql_error());
session_start();


//***** Get today's date
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d");


$firstName = addslashes($_POST['fname']);
$lastName = addslashes($_POST['lname']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO customer_31
            (mb_firstName, 
            mb_lastName,
            mb_phone,
            mb_email,
            mb_date_entered) 
            VALUES 
            ('$firstName', 
            '$lastName', 
            '$phone',
            '$email')";




header("location:index.php");
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason... But is contact.php missing some code `mysql_query($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove mb_date_entered from your INSERT statement in the php

Comment: Tried it, made no difference.  (also added the $today variable back in so it should work regardless)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so while I haven't used .up with form submission I did something similar a bit ago and got it to work by first using getValues() on the parent items, doing some validation and then firing it off to PHP. Here's some code hope it helps:

```
handler: function(btn){
            var vals = btn.parent.parent.getValues();
            vals.time = new Date();

           //basic email validation
            var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
            var result=re.test(vals.email);
            if (result === true){
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: btn.parent.parent.getUrl(),
                params: {   
                        data:Ext.JSON.encode(vals),
                        encoded: vals.toString(),
                        vals: 'other='+JSON.stringify(vals)
                        },
                success: function(res, vals){
                        console.log(res);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(vals));
                        Ext.Viewport.getMasked().hide();
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Thank you', 'Message received successfully.', Ext.emptyFn);
                        Ext.getCmp('contactForm').reset();
                        },

                failure: function(res){
                        console.log('form not submitted', res);
                        Ext.Viewport.getMasked().hide();
                        Ext.getCmp('contactForm').reset();
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Sorry something went wrong', 'Please try that again', Ext.emptyFn);
                        }
                });
            }

            if (result === false){
                Ext.Viewport.getMasked().hide();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid Email', 'Please try again', Ext.emptyFn);
                Ext.getCmp('contactForm').reset();

            }
        }
```

PHP

```
<?php
        $errorMessage = "";

            $db = mysql_connect("YOURDB","USER","PASS");
            if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
            mysql_select_db('formtest' ,$db);

            $json = $_POST['data'];
            $json = utf8_encode($json);

            $insert = "INSERT INTO formdata VALUES ('".$json."')";

            var_dump($_GET);

            if(mysql_query($insert))
            {
                echo('values inserted successfully');
                header("Location: thankyou.html");

            }
            else
            {
                echo('failure' . mysql_error());
            }

            exit();
?>
```